# Trying to insert morris.js chart into Bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, morris.js

I am trying to insert morris.js charts into a carousel, and it works only for the first item with `.active`, or if I add `.active` to other items, but then carousel stops working. I even tried jQuery `addClass` and `removeClass`.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="item active">
  <div class=" first-slide box-body chart-responsive">
    <div class="chart" id="sales-chart" style="height: 300px; position: relative;">

    </div>
  </div><!-- /.box-body -->
</div>
<!-- /.box -->
<div class="item" id="graphElemnt">
  <div class=" second-slide box-body chart-responsive">
    <div class="chart" id="bar-chart" style="height: 300px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item" id="graphElemnt">
  <div class=" third-slide box-body chart-responsive">
    <div class="chart" id="balanced" style="height: 300px; position: relative;">

    </div>
  </div><!-- /.box-body -->
</div>
```

```
var donut = new Morris.Donut({
    element: 'sales-chart',
    resize: true,
    colors: ["#3c8dbc", "#f56954", "#00a65a"],
    data: [
        {label: "huy", value: 12},
        {label: "In-Store Sales", value: 30},
        {label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: 20}
    ],
    hideHover: 'auto'
});
```

Comment: var donut = new Morris.Donut({
          element: 'sales-chart',
          resize: true,
          colors: ["#3c8dbc", "#f56954", "#00a65a"],
          data: [
            {label: "huy", value: 12},
            {label: "In-Store Sales", value: 30},
            {label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: 20}
          ],
          hideHover: 'auto'
        });

Answer (score 0):

Check this out [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vyb6tr7j/3/)

The problem is that when you try to init the charts, they are hidden and they container size is different from what it will be when shown, so we can do it by initializing them only when shown first time

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    var chart= $(this).find('.item.active .chart');
    var id = chart.attr('id');
  if(chart.hasClass('loaded')){
    return true;
  }
  if(id == 'balanced'){
    var donut2 = new Morris.Donut({ 
      element: 'balanced', 
      resize: false, 
      colors: ["#3c8dbc", "#f56954", "#00a65a"], 
      data: [ 
          {label: "Pizda", value: 30}, 
          {label: "Mudak", value: 12}, 
          {label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: 20} 
      ]
  });
  } else if (id = 'bar-chart'){
    var bar = new Morris.Bar({ 
      element: 'bar-chart', 
      resize: false, 
      data: [ 
          {y: '2006', a: 100, b: 90}, 
          {y: '2007', a: 75, b: 65}, 
          {y: '2008', a: 50, b: 40}, 
          {y: '2009', a: 75, b: 65}, 
          {y: '2010', a: 50, b: 40}, 
          {y: '2011', a: 75, b: 65}, 
          {y: '2012', a: 100, b: 90} 
      ], 
      barColors: ['#00a65a', '#f56954'], 
      xkey: 'y', 
      ykeys: ['a', 'b'], 
      labels: ['CPU', 'DISK'], 
      hideHover: 'auto' });
  }
  chart.addClass('loaded');
});
```

Code from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel&stacked=h)

Comment: The problem is it displays normally the .active item only, other two get smaller if you dont add .active, and if you do, the carousel stops working

Comment: var bar = new Morris.Bar({
          element: 'bar-chart',
          resize: true,
          data: [
            {y: '2006', a: 100, b: 90},
            {y: '2007', a: 75, b: 65},
            {y: '2008', a: 50, b: 40},
            {y: '2009', a: 75, b: 65},
            {y: '2010', a: 50, b: 40},
            {y: '2011', a: 75, b: 65},
            {y: '2012', a: 100, b: 90}
          ],
          barColors: ['#00a65a', '#f56954'],
          xkey: 'y',
          ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
          labels: ['CPU', 'DISK'],
          hideHover: 'auto'
        });

Comment: var donut = new Morris.Donut({
          element: 'balanced',
          resize: true,
          colors: ["#3c8dbc", "#f56954", "#00a65a"],
          data: [
            {label: "Pizda", value: 30},
            {label: "Mudak", value: 12},
            {label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: 20}
          ],
          hideHover: 'auto'
        });

Comment: I mean, in the fiddle :)

Comment: Did it, check new fiddle

Comment: Thank you, It works! The only thing is when you click arrow bar charts breaks. Perfect, much better then jquery with add/removeClass

Comment: Yes, actually fiddle also breaks when you click several times

Comment: I got the error if id== 'Bar chart", it was a typo id =